# Type of the "var" variable for structs

Tags: solidity

I have the following line of code in Solidity:

```
var res = result.toSlice();
```

This slices a string. When trying to compile in Truffle, I am getting 
**var is deprecated** error message. I am confused a bit, since I don't know what is the type of the variable here? Neither of my known types work here.

UPD: When changing the variable into, say, `string storage`, I am getting **Type struct strings.slice memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type string storage pointer**.

The `.toSlice()` function of the `strings` library:

```
/*
     * @dev Returns a slice containing the entire string.
     * @param self The string to make a slice from.
     * @return A newly allocated slice containing the entire string.
     */
    function toSlice(string self) internal returns (slice) {
        uint ptr;
        assembly {
            ptr := add(self, 0x20)
        }
        return slice(bytes(self).length, ptr);
    }
```

slice, apparently, is a struct:

```
struct slice {
        uint _len;
        uint _ptr;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I was using the `strings` library, and the variable was a `struct` called `slice`, the `var` is:

```
strings.slice memory res = result.toSlice();
```

Answer (score 1):

`var` is deprecated because it's ambiguous and leaving it up to the compiler could lead to problems.

As you know, the idea here is to cast the left side with the same type as the right side.

`result` looks like a contract and `toSlice()` is a function in that contract. So, in theory this is about the return value type from `toSlice()`.

> This slices a string into a struct.

This makes me go hmmm ... a closer look at `toSlice()` would be helpful.

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**

Try

```
slice res = result.toSlice(...
```

As a style suggestion, to bring it into alignment with the style guide and to reduce confusion, consider replacing `slice` with `SliceStruct` everywhere. So

```
struct SliceStruct {
 ...
```

Comment: .toSlice() is a function in the strings library. I will post it.

Comment: Please, see the updated post.